# Is this possible to train new network based on old one without data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Is this possible to train new smaller network based on already trained network without data? i.e. new network should just try to mimic behaviour of 1st one.

If it's not possible with out data, if there any benefits of have already trained network? i.e. as I understand at least we can use it for pseudo labeling.

Update:

The most relevant paper I have found:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02943.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can say that you are training a network if you are not using any data. But you can always try to get a smaller one, for example by *pruning* the large network (in the simplest case, this means removing weights that have an l2 norm that is close to zero), there is a rich literature on the subject. Also, I think you might find some works in knowledge distillation useful, *e.g.* [Data-Free Knowledge Distillation
for Deep Neural Networks](https://lld-workshop.github.io/papers/LLD_2017_paper_8.pdf) .

Comment: Looks like in this paper they use additional metadata that usually not availible.